# Pointers in C, one example works, one doesn't

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, string-literals

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    char greeting1[10] = "Hello!"; //works
    char *greeting2 = "Hello!";    //works
    int numbers1[10]= {1,2,3};     //works
    int *numbers2 = {1,2,3};       //doesn't work

}
```

It doesn't make sense to me that using pointers work for "greeting2", but not for "numbers2". Is there a simple way to explain why this does not work for "numbers2"?

Answer (score 4):

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

In this declaration

```
char *greeting2 = "Hello!";
```

the string literal has the array type `char[7]` and is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. This pointer expression is used to initialize the pointer  `greeting2`.

When a string literal is used to initialize an array then its elements are used (as initializers) to initialize elements of the array.

```
char greeting1[10] = "Hello!";
```

In fact the above declaration is equivalent to

```
char greeting1[10] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!', '\0' };
```

In this declaration

```
int *numbers2 = {1,2,3};
```

you are trying to initialize a scalar object with a braced list that contains more than one initializer. Such an initialization is invalid. To initialize a scalar object you may use only one initializer in braces.

You could initialize the pointer with a compound literal like

```
int *numbers2 = ( int[] ){1,2,3};
```

In this case the compound literal having the array type `int[3]` again is  implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and this address is used to initialize the pointer `numbers2`.